# Terraform: Unsupported attribute when referencing output variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a question regarding terraform. I have the following setup:

```
rds/
    main.tf
    variables.tf
    imports.tf
    outputs.tf
database-service.tf
main.tf
variables.tf
imports.tf
outputs.tf
```

I have inside the `rds` folder my basic rds terraform scripts (as a module) which I want to use inside the database-service.tf file.

Inside the `rds/outputs.tf` are the following outputs defined:

```
output "foo-aurora-db-endpoint" {
  description = "foo DB Endpoint"
  value = aws_rds_cluster.foo_db_default.endpoint
}

output "foo-aurora-db" {
  description = "foo DB"
  value = aws_rds_cluster.foo_db_default
}

output "foo-aurora-db-port" {
  description = "foo DB Port"
  value = aws_rds_cluster.foo_db_default.port
}
```

These values are referenced inside the `outputs.tf`:

```
output "foo-aurora-db-endpoint" {
  value = module.foo-db.foo-aurora-db-endpoint
}

output "foo-aurora-db-port" {
  value = module.foo-db.foo-aurora-db-port
}
```

My `database-service.tf` looks like this:

```
module "foo-db" {
  source = "./rds"

  ...
  
   }
```

A snippet of my `rds/main.tf` file

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "foo_db_default" {
  cluster_identifier = var.cluster_identifier
  availability_zones = ["eu-central-1a", "eu-central-1b", "eu-central-1c"]
  database_name      = var.database_name
  master_username    = var.master_username
  master_password    = var.master_password
  engine = var.database_engine
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.foo_db_default.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.foo_db_rds.id]
}
```

When I now run `terraform plan` or `apply` I get the following error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on outputs.tf line 35, in output "foo-aurora-db-endpoint":
  35:   value = module.foo-db.foo-aurora-db-endpoint

This value does not have any attributes.
```

What am I missing?

Edit: When referencing `module.foo-db` inside the outputs.tf I get the following output:

```
foo-aurora-db-endpoint = [
  {
    "foo-aurora-db-endpoint" = "<endpoint value>"
    "foo-aurora-db-password" = "<password>"
    "foo-aurora-db-port" = <port>
    "foo-aurora-db-username" = "<username>"
  },
]
```

But I can't figure out how to reference them.

Comment: Your module is declared as `foo-db`?

Comment: Inside the database-service.tf I declare the module to use. See my last edit.

Comment: Just to confirm, in `rds/main.tf` you have the resource called `resource "aws_rds_cluster" "foo_db_default"` ?

Comment: Yes @rk92 , see my last edit.

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21676 -- is it possible that `aws_rds_cluster.foo_db_default.endpoint` is a list or other type of variable?

Comment: Nope, already seen the issue. Copied the scripts from another project where it works.

Comment: Do you use count in the database-service.tf's foo-db block?

Comment: No I don't use the count function. Only the count variable which is set in the `aws_rds_cluster_instance`